# редактирование вывода sidebar в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, шаблоны

Доброго времени суток!
Задался вопросом, когда я подключаю sidebar в wordpress, я могу установить теги которыми будет оборачиваться весь блок sidebar, при этом содержимое выводится списками , а есть возможность изменить вывод содержимого, внутри самого виджета?

```
$args = array(
'name'          => 'Виджет sidebar',
'id'            => 'sidebar',
'description'   => 'Здесь добавляем виджеты сайдбара',
'class'         => '',
'before_widget' => '<div class="callout success">',
'after_widget'  => "</div>\n",
'before_title'  => '<h3>',
    'after_title'   => "</h3>\n",
);
    register_sidebar( $args );
```

на выходе

```
<div class="callout success"><h3>Категории</h3>
        <ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a href="http://wp.local/category/%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8/">новости</a>
</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

хочу убрать

```
<ul>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-3">
```

и заменить своим блоком

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведенным кодом вы устанавливаете параметры `sidebar`, в котором может быть много `widgets`.

Вам надо фильтровать текст самого виджета следующим образом:

```
function filter_widget_text($text) {
  $search = array('<ul>','<li class="cat-item cat-item-3">');
  $replace = array('','......');
  $text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
  return $text;
}
add_filter('widget_text', 'filter_widget_text');
```

Comment: Спасибо! про фильтр не подумал!